# Event-sourcing: when (and not) should I use Message Queue?

Tags: asynchronous, message-queue, event-sourcing

I am building a project from scratch using event-sourcing with Java and Cassandra.

My apps we be based on microservices and in some use cases information will be processed asynchronously. I was wondering what part a Message Queue (such as RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ Artemis, Kafka, etc) would play to improve the technology stack in this environment and if I understand the scenarios if I won't use it.

Answer (score 34):

I would start with separating messaging infrastructure like RabbitMQ from event streaming/storing/processing like Kafka. These are two different things made for two (or more) different purposes.

Concerning the event sourcing, you have to have a place where you must store events. This storage must be append-only and support fast reads of unstructured data based on an identity. One example of such persistence is the [EventStore](http://www.geteventstore.com).

Event sourcing goes together with CQRS, which means you have to project your changes (events) to another store, which you can query. This is done by projecting events to that store, this is where events get processed to change the domain object state. It is important to understand that using message infrastructure for projections is generally a bad idea. This is due to the nature of messaging and two-phase commit issue.

If you look at how events get persisted, you can see that they get saved to the store as one transaction. If you then need to publish events, this will be another transaction. Since you are dealing with two different pieces of infrastructure, things can get broken.

The messaging issue as such is that messages are usually guaranteed to be delivered "at least once" and the order of messages is usually not guaranteed. Also, when your message consumer fails and NACKs the message, it will be redelivered but usually a bit later, again breaking the sequence.

The ordering and duplication concerns, whoever, do not apply to event streaming servers like Kafka. Also, the EventStore will guarantee once only event delivery in order if you use catch-up subscription.

In my experience, messages are used to send commands and to implement event-driven architecture to connect independent services in a reactive way. Event stores, at the other hand, are used to persist events and only events that get there are then projected to the query store and also get published to the message bus.

Comment: Thank you Alexey, quick question here: how is that "the ordering and duplication concerns, whoever, do not apply to event streaming servers like Kafka"? If you have concurrent subscribers you inevitably start having out-of-order issues if those concurrent subscribers are interdependent, so there should be some custom synchronisation implemented among them based on business rules of the specific app. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I personally have no experience with Kafka but I watched the talk of Martin Kleppmann on DDDU 2016 https://dddeurope.com/2016/martin-kleppmann.html where he explains that when they designed Kafka they aimed for strict event ordering. I also know that EventStore guarantees event order when using catch/up subscription. Inevitably this guarantee breaks when you set competing consumers on your event streams, there is nothing you can do there to guarantee ordering. Asynchronous processing will also break the ordering.

Comment: I see. I'm asking because in any HA system you have to have competing consumers for fault tolerance, and looks like there is no mechanism to automatically handle out of order situations for such systems.

Comment: @IlliakaillI yes, I believe with competing consumers generic ordering is theoretically impossible and must be handled by the system using some attributes on incoming messages and intra-process communication.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you are clear on the distinction between send(command) and publish(event).  Udi Dahan touches on that topic in his essay on [busses and brokers](http://udidahan.com/2011/03/24/bus-and-broker-pubsub-differences/).

In most cases where you are event sourcing, you do *not* want to be reconstructing state from published events.  If you need state, then query the technical authority/book of record for the history, and reconstruct the state from the history.

On the other hand, event *driven* activity off of a message queue should be fine.  When a single event (plus the subscriber's state) has everything you need, then running off of the bus is fine.

In some cases, you might do both.  For example, if you were updating cached views, you'd subscribe to various `BobChanged` events to know when your cached data was stale; to rebuild a stale view, you would reload a representation of the history and transform it into an updated view.

Answer (score 6):

In the world of event-sourcing applications, message queues usually allow you to implement publish-subscribe pattern style of communication between producers and consumers. Also, they usually help you with delivery guarantees: which messages were delivered to which subscribers and which ones were not.

But they don't store all messages indefinitely. You need to have an event store to do any kind of event sourcing.

The question is not 'to queue or not to queue', but it is more like:

- can this thing store huge volume of events indefinitely?
- does it have publish-subscribe capabilities?
- does it provide at-least-once delivery guarantees?

So, you should use something like [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) or [EventStore](https://geteventstore.com/) to have all that out-of-the-box. Alternatively, you can combine event store with message queue manually, but this is going to be more involved.