# Dynamic Queue Based on Key

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I have a system with many users.
Every user is allowed to do 1 action at a time.
I want to create a "different" queue for every user.
So let's say I push

```
{user: 1, todo: 'Get Money'}

{user: 1, todo: 'Get Pizza'}

{user: 1, todo: 'Get a car'}

{user: 2, todo: 'Get Money'}

{user: 2, todo: 'Get a car'}
```

I have basically created two queues.

Let's assume I have 2 or more workers. Only one worker will work per queue.

I am trying to find a queue system that can do it without using an external database.

Which queue system could handle it the best?

Comment: Look at temporal.io. It would solve your problem much more elegantly than a queue. Here is a post explains how it can be used to solve a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263335/job-queue-with-job-affinity/56615120#56615120

Answer (score -1):

mongo queue will do the job

http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/schema/queues/

https://dltlabs.medium.com/mongodb-queue-and-processing-in-distributed-systems-a805b32f6e76

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/schema/chapter7/

https://github.com/chilts/mongodb-queue